# How can I customize default work item state's color

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I want to customize the color of work item states (e.g. on user story set the orange color on resolved state) but in the contextual menu, the only thing I can do is to view the state, not edit:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You can only change the color for your custom states, not for the system states.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: I have the same question for a custom state. How would I do that? TIA

Comment: @SergeWautier When you add new state you can choose the color.